# Deleted nginx executable and can't reinstall it

Tags: apt, server, nginx

I deleted the `nginx` executable manually (I think it may have been in `/usr/sbin`)

Then I uninstalled the `nginx` package (`sudo apt purge nginx`).
Now when I install `nginx` again (`sudo apt install nginx`) the executable is not installed (and the package is only `45.1 kB`, which can't be right).

How can I install `nginx` again?

I also compiled the source code and installed `nginx` with `sudo make install`, but when I try to `sudo nginx` I  get the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/var/www/html/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so" failed (/var/www/html/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:1
```

(When I search my directory tree, I find that the `ngx_http_image_filter_module.so` library is in `/usr/lib/nginx/modules`, so I don't know why the executable is looking for it in `/var/www`.)

(Running Ubuntu 20.04.)

Answer (score 1):

In case you have already taken backup of your system then only restore the executable(/usr/sbin/nginx) and if you don't have backup,
You have to  just installed the same version of nginx in other machine and do copy the /usr/sbin/nginx to previous machine, and set the permission -rwxr-xr-x of /usr/sbin/nginx.

Comment: The answer is not unclear, you bot